# How can I make the GUI buttons respond properly?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jbutton

I have written the following code, and it seems to be working smoothly except for the "exit info" button in the info box and the text in the info box. Firstly, the text in the info box (this is on a label) refuses to show up. Second, the "exit info" button does not appear at the location I have set for it. Any advice on what I could do to make this run properly?
Thanks

Note: I am very inexperienced with Java and therefore probably will not fully understand answers unless they are written as though they are for kindergarten students :)

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class CombineInputWindow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Create the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("New GUI");// Title the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);// add close function

    // Create the label:
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("");// No text is added
    textLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,240));// Set the size of the label
    frame.getContentPane().add(textLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);// Add the label to the frame

    // The following three lines set the frame up further
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Create the panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);// Add panel to frame

    // Create lbutton (size, text, etc.)
    JButton lbutton = new JButton("Move Left");
    panel.add(lbutton);
    lbutton.setSize(128,32);
    lbutton.setVisible(true);
    lbutton.setLocation(0,208);

    // Create rbutton (size, text, etc.)
    JButton rbutton = new JButton("Move right");
    panel.add(rbutton);
    rbutton.setSize(128,32);
    rbutton.setVisible(true);
    rbutton.setLocation(192,208);

    // Create dodge button (size, text, etc.)
    JButton btndodge = new JButton("Duck");
    panel.add(btndodge);
    btndodge.setSize(64,32);
    btndodge.setVisible(true);
    btndodge.setLocation(128,208);

    // Create exit button (size, text, etc.)
    JButton btnexit = new JButton("Exit");
    panel.add(btnexit);
    btnexit.setSize(64,32);
    btnexit.setVisible(true);
    btnexit.setLocation(256,0);

    // Create info button (size, text, etc.)
    JButton btninfo = new JButton("Info");
    panel.add(btninfo);
    btninfo.setSize(64,32);
    btninfo.setVisible(true);
    btninfo.setLocation(192,0);

    // Add function to the lbutton for mouse event
    lbutton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        int vbtnclicks = 0; 
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            vbtnclicks = vbtnclicks + 1;

            //The following code prints out the number of times the user has clicked the button
            if (vbtnclicks > 2) { 
                System.out.println("You moved left " + vbtnclicks + " times!");
                }

            else if (vbtnclicks == 1) {
                System.out.println("You moved left once!");
                }

            else if (vbtnclicks == 2){
                System.out.println("You moved left twice!");
            }

            else {
                // The following code should not have to show up
                System.out.println("I get the sense this code has been meddled with...");
            }

        }
    });

    // Add mouse event for rbutton
    rbutton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        int cbtnclicks = 0; 
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            cbtnclicks = cbtnclicks + 1;

            //The following code prints out the number of times the user has clicked the button
            if (cbtnclicks > 2) { 
                System.out.println("You moved right " + cbtnclicks + " times!");
                }

            else if (cbtnclicks == 1) {
                System.out.println("You moved right once!");
                }

            else if (cbtnclicks == 2){
                System.out.println("You moved right twice!");
            }

            else {
                // The following code should not have to show up
                System.out.println("I get the sense this code has been meddled with...");
            }

        }
    });

    // Add mouse event for btndodge
            btndodge.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                int dbtnclicks = 0; 
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    dbtnclicks = dbtnclicks + 1;

                    //The following code prints out the number of times the user has clicked the button
                    if (dbtnclicks > 2) { 
                        System.out.println("You ducked " + dbtnclicks + " times!");
                        }

                    else if (dbtnclicks == 1) {
                        System.out.println("You ducked once!");
                        }

                    else if (dbtnclicks == 2){
                        System.out.println("You ducked twice!");
                    }

                    else {
                        // The following code should not have to show up
                        System.out.println("I get the sense this code has been meddled with...");
                    }

                }
            });

    // Add mouse event and exit command to the exit button
    btnexit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {


            System.exit(0);
    }
    });

    // Add function to the "Info" button
    btninfo.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

            // Open an Info Window with specific settings
            JFrame inframe = new JFrame("Info");

            JLabel inlabel = new JLabel("This is the info text.");
            inlabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            inframe.getContentPane().add(inlabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            inframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inframe.pack();
            inframe.setVisible(true);

            JPanel inpanel = new JPanel();
            inframe.add(inpanel);

            JButton inextbtn = new JButton("Exit Info");
            inpanel.add(inextbtn);

            inextbtn.setSize(96,24);
            inextbtn.setVisible(true);
            inextbtn.setLocation(0,0);

            inextbtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

                    inframe.dispose();
                    }
            });
        }
    });
    }
```

}

Comment: You don't want to use a mouse listener for JButtons, try using an event listener instead.

Comment: @EliSadoff: A MouseListener *is* an event listener. Perhaps you wanted to say "ActionListener", and if so, you'd be right.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I meant `ActionListener` not event listener. Sorry about that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem, why the infoLabel isn't showing, is due to your calling `setVisible(true)` on its JFrame before you added the JPanel that held it to its contentPane. Always call `setVisible(true)` **after** adding all components to your JFrame. Your also covering up the JLabel by adding the JPanel to the JFrame after it since the inFrame uses BorderLayout.

Other problems:

- Yes, use ActionListeners for JButtons not MouseListeners. An ActionListener will respond if the button has focus and the space bar is pressed -- which is expected and correct behavior. A MouseListener will not. Also if you disable a JButton, an ActionListener won't work, again this is expected and correct, and again the MouseListener misbehaves here.
- Don't set absolute sizes or positions of your GUI components but rather let the component default preferred sizes and the container layout managers do this heavy lifting for you.
- The info window should be a JDialog and not a JFrame since a visible application should only have one main frame window, one JFrame.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CombineInput2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        add(new JButton(new InfoAction("Info", this)));
        add(new JButton(new ExitAction()));
    }
}

class InfoAction extends AbstractAction {
    private MainPanel mainPanel;
    private JDialog dialog;

    public InfoAction(String name, MainPanel mainPanel) {
        super(name);
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (dialog == null) {
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(mainPanel);
            dialog = new JDialog(win, "Info", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.add(new DialogPanel());
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(win);
        }
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DialogPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int DP_WIDTH = 250;
    private static final int DP_HEIGHT = 100;
    private String text = "This is the info text.";
    private JLabel infoLabel = new JLabel(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);

    public DialogPanel() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        Action exitAction = new ExitAction();
        exitAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Exit Info");
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(exitAction));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(infoLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension prefSz = super.getPreferredSize();

        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return prefSz;
        }
        int width = Math.max(prefSz.width, DP_WIDTH);
        int height = Math.max(prefSz.height, DP_HEIGHT);
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}

class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
    public ExitAction() {
        super("Exit");
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_X);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
        if (c == null) {
            return;
        }
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(c);
        if (win != null) {
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried what you suggested, and it works much better than my original program;